# Condensing Javascript Conditional Block Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 blocks of code that all work fine, but each slightly differ by the ID I am targeting. I want to condense all of this to a single block of code. I am aware of attribute begins with and attribute ends with, but this is a little complex and not sure how I'd apply it.

As you can see I have:
accountFirewawallFilter, globalFirewallFilter and firewallFilter.

```
function toggleType(field, initial){
switch($("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"Type").val()){
  case "any":
    $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"").parent().show();
    $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('name', "accountFirewallFilter["+field+"]");
    $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"").val(null);
    $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"Options").parent().hide();
    $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"Options").prop('name', "accountFirewallFilter["+field+"Options]");
    break;
  case "address":
    $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"").parent().show();
    $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('disabled', false);
    $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('name', "accountFirewallFilter["+field+"]");
    if(!initial){
      $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"").val(null);
    }
    $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"Options").parent().hide();
    $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"Options").prop('name', "accountFirewallFilter["+field+"Options]");
    break;
  case "network":
    $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"").parent().hide();
    $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('name', "accountFirewallFilter["+field+"Disabled]");
    $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"Options").parent().show();
    $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"Options").prop('name', "accountFirewallFilter["+field+"]");

    // Used to load the "+field+" into the dropdown on edit
    if($("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"").val()){
      $("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"Options").val($("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"").val());
    }

    break;
}
}

toggleType('source', true);
toggleType('destination', true);
// $("[id$='Filter_sourceType']").change(function(){ toggleType('source', false); });
// $("[id$='Filter_destinationType']").change(function(){ toggleType('destination', false); });

// function toggleType(field, initial){
// switch($("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"Type").val()){
//   case "any":
//     $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"").parent().show();
//     $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('disabled', true);
//     $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('name', "globalFirewallFilter["+field+"]");
//     $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"").val(null);
//     $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"Options").parent().hide();
//     $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"Options").prop('name', "globalFirewallFilter["+field+"Options]");
//     break;
//   case "address":
//     $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"").parent().show();
//     $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('disabled', false);
//     $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('name', "globalFirewallFilter["+field+"]");
//     if(!initial){
//       $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"").val(null);
//     }
//     $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"Options").parent().hide();
//     $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"Options").prop('name', "globalFirewallFilter["+field+"Options]");
//     break;
//   case "network":
//     $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"").parent().hide();
//     $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('disabled', true);
//     $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('name', "globalFirewallFilter["+field+"Disabled]");
//     $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"Options").parent().show();
//     $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"Options").prop('name', "globalFirewallFilter["+field+"]");

//     // Used to load the "+field+" into the dropdown on edit
//     if($("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"").val()){
//       $("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"Options").val($("#globalFirewallFilter_"+field+"").val());
//     }

//     break;
// }
// }

// toggleType('source', true);
// toggleType('destination', true);

// $("[id$='Filter_sourceType']").change(function(){ toggleType('source', false); });
// $("[id$='Filter_destinationType']").change(function(){ toggleType('destination', false); });

// function toggleType(field, initial){
// switch($("#firewallFilter_"+field+"Type").val()){
//   case "any":
//     $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"").parent().show();
//     $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('disabled', true);
//     $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('name', "firewallFilter["+field+"]");
//     $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"").val(null);
//     $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"Options").parent().hide();
//     $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"Options").prop('name', "firewallFilter["+field+"Options]");
//     break;
//   case "address":
//     $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"").parent().show();
//     $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('disabled', false);
//     $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('name', "firewallFilter["+field+"]");
//     if(!initial){
//       $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"").val(null);
//     }
//     $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"Options").parent().hide();
//     $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"Options").prop('name', "firewallFilter["+field+"Options]");
//     break;
//   case "network":
//     $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"").parent().hide();
//     $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('disabled', true);
//     $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"").prop('name', "firewallFilter["+field+"Disabled]");
//     $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"Options").parent().show();
//     $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"Options").prop('name', "firewallFilter["+field+"]");

//     // Used to load the "+field+" into the dropdown on edit
//     if($("#firewallFilter_"+field+"").val()){
//       $("#firewallFilter_"+field+"Options").val($("#firewallFilter_"+field+"").val());
//     }

//     break;
// }
// }
```

Comment: Is the large portion of commented code supposed to be there? Are the blocks the code in each `case`?

Comment: Each function is what I am referring to as blocks

Comment: I want one toggle type function applicable to each firewall type

Comment: Ah, alright I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the only different in each block of code is the following names:

- accountFirewallFilter
- firewallFilter
- globalFirewallFilter

With that in mind you can create a third `filter` parameter, in which you can give those three items as a value.

```
function toggleType(field, initial, filter) {
 switch($("#"+filter+"_"+field+"Type").val()) {
  case "any":
    $("#"+filter+"_"+field+"").parent().show();
    $("#"+filter+"_"+field+"").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#"+filter+"_"+field+"").prop('name', filter+"["+field+"]");
    $("#"+filter+"_"+field+"").val(null);
    $("#"+filter+"_"+field+"Options").parent().hide();
    $("#"+filter+"_"+field+"Options").prop('name', filter+"["+field+"Options]");
    break;
  case "address":
    ...
 }
}
```

Then give each value as a parameter (we could even make this into a loop, with the three items in an array repeating `source` and `destination`):

```
toogleType('source', true, "accountFirewallFilter");
toogleType('destination', true, "accountFirewallFilter");
toogleType('source', true, "firewallFilter");
toogleType('destination', true, "firewallFilter");
toogleType('source', true, "globalFirewallFilter");
toogleType('destination', true, "globalFirewallFilter");
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to simplify the above code is to replace the `switch` with an object map instead.

1. Create an object, say `map` which maps the case strings as keys, to functions that perform the relevant action for that key
2. Then use `map[$("#accountFirewallFilter_"+field+"Type").val()](field);` to execute the relevant function with respect to the `field`.

A short example of converting a switch into a map as described above:

**Switch**

```
switch(input) {
    case "hello":
        alert('You said hello');
        break;

    case "goodbye":
        alert('You said goodbye');
        break;
}
```

**Alternatively expressing the switch with an object used as a map**

```
// Defining the map - the case strings are the 'keys' and the required behaviours are the 'values'
var map = {
    hello: function(option) { alert('You said hello.  ' + 'Option for this func = ' + option); },
    goodbye: function(option) { alert('You said goodbye.  ' + 'Option for this func = ' + option); }
}; 

map[input]('option'); // Call required function
```

However do note you should do a check with the map method that `input` (as in above example) is in fact present in `map`, otherwise you will be invoking `undefined`.  This check is the equivalent of supplying a `default` case in a `switch` statement.

The way of doing this with maps is arguably much cleaner and is easier to read and edit what happens in each case - though, this of course varies depending on opinion.